# Manipulating Data in 2D Array

Tags: c

I want to manipulate data in 2D array an entire row at a time; something like this:

```
{
uint8 2d_Array[5][4] = {0};

2d_Array[0][4] = {0x12, 0x3E, 0x32};  // <-- Error here.
2d_Array[1][4] = {0x5F, 0x17, 0xE4};
...
}
```

However, the above code gives an error: *`Expected expression before '{'`*.

Is something similar to the above possible in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initialize a 2D array:

```
uint8 2d_Array[5][4] = 
   {
      {0x12, 0x3E, 0x32, 0},   // 2d_Array[0][0-3]
      {0x5F, 0x17, 0xE4, 0},   // 2d_Array[1][0-3]
       ...
      {0, 0, 0, 0}             // 2d_Array[4][0-3] 
   };
```

Or, perhaps:

```
   memcpy(2d_array[0], "\x12\x3E\x32", 3);
   memcpy(2d_array[1], "\x5F\x17\xE4", 3);
```

Or, perhaps (if you want to also copy a '\0' at the end of each):

```
   memcpy(2d_array[0], "\x12\x3E\x32", 4);
   memcpy(2d_array[1], "\x5F\x17\xE4", 4);
```

Comment: Yes, this I know, but I want use it one by one according to my application

Answer (score 0):

```
2d_Array[0][4] = {0x12, 0x3E, 0x32};
```

On the one side you have a uint8 and on the other an array of uint8. That cannot work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form

```
<array> = {0x12, 0x3E, 0x32};
```

only to initialize an array. To set elements of the array, you have to set them one by one.

```
2d_Array[0][1] = 0x12;
2d_Array[0][2] = 0x3E;
2d_Array[0][3] = 0x32;
```

etc.

**PS** You can't have a variable name that starts with `2`.

Comment: Yes, this I know, but I want use it one by one according to my application.

Comment: @user3665714 great, but *arrays are not allowed as lvalues in C*. They can be initialized as shown here. otherwise you're down to the elements and looping, `memcpy`-ing if you're *really* creative.

Answer (score 0):

The first *error of your program is the variable name* = **2d_Array**
**First character should be a alphabet or underscore**. [Refer](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-variable-nameing-rules/)

Initializing/Storing values in a two dimensional array

```
uint8 2d_Array[5][4] = {0};            //This initializes all the elements of array to 0
2d_Array[0][4] = 0x12;                 // Assigns value 0x12 to the element in of 0th row & 4th column
```

**And the following initialization is wrong,**

Array[1](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-variable-nameing-rules/) = {0x5F, 0x17, 0xE4};

**A row of an array can be initialized using the above method only while declaring the array as**

```
uint8 Array[5][4]={ {0}
                       {0x12, 0x3E, 0x32}
                       {0x5F, 0x17, 0xE4}
                   };
```